# how to get an item in an iteration using foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

Im having a hard time extracting an item in an array, for example trying to retrieve a post in posts.

this is the **error**

keep in mind everything works, i can extract posts but im trying to successfully show the delete button to users.

im following laravel polices, to show a delete button for the user who made the post

laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates

> Undefined variable: post (View:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli42/resources/views/home.blade.php)

this is what i have so far

```
 public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::with('user')->get();

        return view('home', compact('posts'));

    }
```

home.blade.php

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">
        <figure>
            <p> <% post.body %></p>
            <p>  <% post.created_at %></p>
        </figure>
        <span>

     @foreach($posts as $post)
                    @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post) )
                    <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)">
                    </i>
                    @endif
                 @endforeach
            <span><a href="/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what im doing wrong

it needs to show one close button not 3

[image]

Comment: Why that `foreach()` is needed at `index()` function?

Comment: can you please print what response you got for  $posts = Post::with('user')->get();

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon needed to use the laravel polices 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates so i can show delete button for a user

Comment: @JiteshNK it works but i need to show the delete button if a user owns the post

Comment: Your function has multiple return statements. As soon as any of them is reached, the function stops executing code. This would never work...

Comment: i still confused, just want to show the delete button if a user made the post is all

Comment: @BARNOWL You don't need that `foreach` loop in your function. and you must return `$posts` to the view, not `$post` that does not exist.

Comment: i updated the thread take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) returns program control to the calling module. Execution
>   resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.

You are sending request on method **getPosts** for collecting **posts**. So you don't need to return **posts** *variable* by **index** method. Then you need it in **getPosts**.

You are using **angular** and in this case you need to have variable about *delete availability* but this variable you need in javascript. Just add it in controller and send to angular, then use `ng-if` attribute in angular for *show/hide* delete button.

In this case you need to change `getPosts` method as it is in answer what will add **deletable** variable in every **post** then you can use `post.deletable` in angular. What you need to end this task is that add `ng-if="post.deletable"` to `<i>` tag what means *if delete post is available show this tag(button)*.

Controller

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return response()->json(Post::with('user')->get()->map(function(Post $post){
        return collect($post->toArray())->put('deletable', auth()->user()->can('delete', $post));
    }));
}

public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

It looks like you are using [Angular](https://angularjs.org). For this case your [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade) seems good.

In this case you don't need `$posts` `variable` in **view** and you don't need `@foreach` too in **blade**.

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">
        <figure>
            <p> <% post.body %></p>
            <p>  <% post.created_at %></p>
        </figure>
        <span>
            <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-if="post.deletable"></i>
            <span><a href="/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i updated the post, it needs to show one close button. not 3 thank you.

Comment: @BARNOWL if my answer helped you check it please.

Comment: @BARNOWL You are getting 3 close button because you have three rows in your post table.

Comment: @Guja1501 it doesnt work, the post varaible is undefined, sorry for the late response.

Comment: Okey... You are using angular... in this case you need to set another variable in post what means `true` if user can delete and `false` if cant.

Comment: I dont understand, im confused .. can you show me im so sorry

Comment: @BARNOWL you can see updated answer. don't miss `ng-if` in blade.php

Comment: let me try this

Comment: @Guja1501 the button still doesnt show, keep in mind im using https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates

Comment: @guja what do you mean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159664/discussion-between-guja1501-and-barnowl).

Answer (score -3):

You should try this:

**Function**

```
public function index() {

    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();


    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">
        <figure>
            <p> <% post.body %></p>
            <p>  <% post.created_at %></p>
        </figure>
        <span>
          @foreach(posts as $post)
            @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post->id) )
            <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)">
            </i>
            @endif
         @endforeach

            <span><a href="/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't work im following the laravel polices 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates

i get this 

`{"id":26,"body":"sdsdsdsd","user_id":1,"created_at":"2017-11-23 08:16:38","updated_at":"2017-11-23 08:16:38","user":{"id":1,"name":"Eli Hood","email":"eli.hood@aol.com","created_at":"2017-11-13 00:19:05","updated_at":"2017-11-13 00:19:05"}}`

it needs to successfully show the delete button. along with the posts.

Comment: Surely the second return statement is never reached given that there are $posts.  Assume the premature return is emitting json.